# Vanilla Javascript Adding This.Title, Value, Amount for Expense Form on Budget App

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constructor, this, es6-class

Hello I'm developing a budget app following a tutorial via Coding Addict, I'm having trouble with the submitExpenseForm of the code. It's suppose to work when the user submit multiple "expenses" the problem after the first values the "expense.title" & "expense.amount" has been appended to the html the 2nd+ of the entries for the expense form of the app keeps showing up as undefined and NaN and it's been wrecking my brain for the past two days with rewatching the video, research and coming up with some other codes that didn't work. Any tips would be greatly helpful, thank you so much.

```js
//JS tutorial from freecodecamp.org
// window.alert("javascript is loaded and ready!");
class UI {
    //setting variables
    constructor() {
        this.budgetFeedback = document.querySelector(".budget-feedback");
        this.expenseFeedback = document.querySelector(".expense-feedback");
        this.budgetForm = document.getElementById("budget-form");
        this.budgetInput = document.getElementById("budget-input");
        this.budgetAmount = document.getElementById("budget-amount");
        this.expenseAmount = document.getElementById("expense-amount");
        this.balance = document.getElementById("balance");
        this.balanceAmount = document.getElementById("balance-amount");
        this.expenseForm = document.getElementById("expense-form");
        this.expenseInput = document.getElementById("expense-input");
        this.amountInput = document.getElementById("amount-input");
        this.expenseList = document.getElementById("expense-list");
        this.itemList = [];
        this.itemID = 0;
    }
    //submit button budget, function will run the following code
    submitBudgetForm(){
        // console.log('hello from es6');
        const value = this.budgetInput.value;
        if(value === '' || value <0){
            this.budgetFeedback.classList.add('showItem');
            this.budgetFeedback.innerHTML = `<p>field can't be empty or negative.</p>`;
            console.log('error message will appear on DOM');
        }
        else{
            this.budgetAmount.textContent = value;
            this.budgetInput.value = "";
            this.showBalance();
        }
    }
    //show balance
    showBalance(){
        const expense = this.totalExpense();
        //parseInt would convert argument into a string (string of numbers with no [,]).
        const total = parseInt(this.budgetAmount.textContent) - expense;
        this.balanceAmount.textContent = total;
        if(total < 0){
            this.balance.classList.remove("showGreen", "showBlack");
            this.balance.classList.add("showRed")
        }
        else if(total > 0){
            this.balance.classList.remove("showRed", "showBlack");
            this.balance.classList.add("showGreen");
        }
        else if(total === 0){
            this.balance.classList.remove("showRed", "showGreen");
            this.balance.classList.add("showBlack");
        }
        // console.log(`hey I'm getting a hold of 'this' keyword`);
    }
    //submit expense form function
    submitExpenseForm(){
        const expenseValue = this.expenseInput.value;
        const amountValue = this.amountInput.value;
        if(expenseValue === '' || amountValue === '' || amountValue < 0)
        {
            this.expenseFeedback.classList.add('showItem');
            this.expenseFeedback.innerHTML = `<p>field can't be empty or negative.</p>`
        }
        else {
            let amount = parseInt(amountValue);
            this.expenseInput = "";
            this.amountInput = "";

            let expense = {
                id:this.itemID,
                title:expenseValue,
                amount:amount,

            }
            this.itemID++;
            this.itemList.push(expense);
            this.addExpense(expense);
            this.showBalance();
            //show balance
        }
    }

    //add expense

    addExpense(expense){
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('expense');
        div.innerHTML = `<div class="expense-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline">
        <h6 class="expense-title mb-0 text-uppercase list-item">-${expense.title}</h6>
        <h5 class="expense-amount mb-0 list-item">${expense.amount}</h5>
        <div class="expense-icons list-item">
         <a href="#" class="edit-icon mx-2" data-id="${expense.id}">
          <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
         </a>
         <a href="#" class="delete-icon" data-id="${expense.id}">
          <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
         </a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>`;
      this.expenseList.appendChild(div);
    }
    //total expense
    totalExpense(){
        let total = 0;
        if(this.itemList.length > 0){
            console.log(this.itemList);
        }
        this.expenseAmount.textContent = total;

        return total;
    }
}

function eventListeners(){
    const budgetForm = document.getElementById('budget-form');
    const expenseForm = document.getElementById('expense-form');
    const expenseList = document.getElementById('expense-list');

    //new UI Class
    const ui = new UI()

    //budget form submit
    budgetForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        ui.submitBudgetForm();

    });

    //expense form submit
    expenseForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        ui.submitExpenseForm();

    })

    //expense click (expense value & title edit and trash)
    expenseList.addEventListener('click', function(){
        
    })

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    eventListeners();
})
```

```css
:root {
    --mainWhite: #f5f5f5f5;
    --mainDark: #333333;
    --mainGreen: #317b22;
    --mainRed: #b80c09;
    --mainBlue: #05668d;
    --mainYellow: yellow;
  }
  
  body {
    background: var(--mainWhite);
    color: var(--mainDark);
  }
  .budget-feedback,
  .expense-feedback {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .budget-form {
    border: 0.15rem solid var(--mainGreen);
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  .expense-form {
    border: 0.15rem solid var(--mainRed);
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  .budget-submit {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0.1rem solid var(--mainGreen);
    color: var(--mainGreen);
  }
  .expense-submit {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0.1rem solid var(--mainRed);
    color: var(--mainRed);
  }
  .expense-submit:hover {
    background: var(--mainRed);
    color: var(--mainWhite);
  }
  .budget-submit:hover {
    background: var(--mainGreen);
    color: var(--mainDark);
  }
  
  .budget-input {
    border: 0.05rem solid var(--mainGreen) !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .expense-input {
    border: 0.05rem solid var(--mainRed) !important;
  }
  .expense-group {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .expense-amount,
  .expense-title {
    color: var(--mainRed);
  }
  .edit-icon {
    color: var(--mainBlue);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none !important;
  }
  .delete-icon {
    color: var(--mainRed);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none !important;
  }
  .edit-icon:hover {
    color: var(--mainBlue);
  }
  .delete-icon:hover {
    color: var(--mainRed);
  }
  .showItem {
    display: block;
  }
  .info-title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .budget {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: var(--mainGreen);
  }
  .expense {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: var(--mainRed);
  }
  .balance {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
  .budget-icon,
  .expense-icon,
  .balance-icon {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: var(--mainBlue);
  }
  .showRed {
    color: var(--mainRed);
  }
  .showGreen {
    color: var(--mainGreen);
  }
  .showBlack {
    color: var(--mainDark);
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .budget {
      font-size: 2.6rem;
      color: var(--mainGreen);
    }
    .expense {
      font-size: 2.6rem;
      color: var(--mainRed);
    }
    .balance {
      font-size: 2.6rem;
    }
    .budget-icon,
    .expense-icon,
    .balance-icon {
      font-size: 3.5rem;
      color: var(--mainBlue);
    }
  }
  .list-item {
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .expense-item {
    height: 2rem;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./fontawesome-free-5.15.2-web/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<title>UPPERclassman</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <!--title of app-->
            <div class="col-11 mx-auto p-3">
                <h3 class="UPPERclassman">UPPERclassman</h3> 
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 my-3">
                    <!--budget alert message-->
                    <div class="budget-feedback alert alert-danger text-capitalize">budget feedback</div>
                    <!---budget form-->
                    <form id="budget-form" class="budget-form">
                        <h5>Please enter your budget</h5>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control budget-input" id="budget-input">
                        </div>
                        <!--submit button-->
                        <button type="submit" class="btn text-capitalize budget-submit" id="budget-submit">calculate</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="row my-3">
                        <div class="col-4 text-center mb-2">
                            <h6 class="info-title">Budget</h6>
                            <span class="budget-icon"><i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave fa-2x"></i></span>
                            <h4 class="mt-2 budget" id="budget"><span>$</span><span id="budget-amount">0</span></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 text-center">
                            <h6 class="info-title">Expense</h6>
                            <span class="expense-icon"><i class="far fa-credit-card fa-2x"></i></span>
                            <h4 class="mt-2 expense" id="expense"><span>$</span><span id="expense-amount">0</span></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 text-center">
                            <h6 class="info-title">Balance</h6>
                            <span class="balance-icon"><i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd fa-2x"></i></span>
                            <h4 class="mt-2 balance" id="balance"><span>$</span><span id="balance-amount">0</span></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 my-3">
                        <div class="expense-feedback alert alert-danger text-capitalize">expense feedback</div>
                        <form id="expense-form" class="expense-form">
                            <h5 class="text-capitalize">please enter your expense</h5>
                            <div class="form-group expense-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control expense-input" id="expense-input">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group expense-group">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control expense-input" id="amount-input">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn text-capitalize expense-submit" id="expense-submit">add expense</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 my-3">
                        <div class="expense-list" id="expense-list">
                            <div class="expense-list__info d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                            <h5 class="list-item">expense title</h5>
                            <h5 class="list-item">expense value</h5>
                            <h5 class="list-item"></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <!-- jquery -->
 <!-- <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> -->
 <!-- bootstrap js -->
 <!-- <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> -->
 <!-- script js -->
 <script src="budget.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines:

```
        this.expenseInput = "";
        this.amountInput = "";
```

are clearing your reference to the controls.

Perhaps they should be:

```
        this.expenseInput.value = "";
        this.amountInput.value = "";
```